# Can a transformer transfer all power?

Tags: electric-circuits, power

How can the transformer transfer exact power from primary winding to secondary winding if there are core losses, eddy current losses and hysteresis losses?

Answer (score 1):

No real transformer is lossless, the output power is always smaller than the input power.

One can, however, build transformers that have extremely precise voltage and current ratios (but none of those are transferring any power). Such transformers are being used in calibration and measurement applications.